# How do you configure Single Request Architecture for Google Publisher Tags in a React application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-publisher-tag

I'm trying to implement enableSingleRequest() for Google Publisher Tags in a React application.
I have it set up the way google suggests:

```
    this.googletag.cmd.push(() => {
      if (this.props.enableSingleRequest) {
        // Infinite scroll requires SRA
        this.googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
      }

      // add support for async loading
      this.googletag.pubads().enableAsyncRendering();

      // collapse div without ad
      this.googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();

      // load ad with slot refresh
      this.googletag.pubads().disableInitialLoad();

      // enable google publisher tag
      this.googletag.enableServices();
    });
```

I have 6 ads on one of the pages, and I'm still seeing 6 requests. 
I'm also seeing multiple slots have the exact same ad, which is the problem that `SRA` is used to resolve. 
I have a `react adComponent` that gets loaded in each slot. 
Do I need to re-architect how individual adSlots are loaded? 
Maybe using redux because it seems like the call to enableSingleRequest() should be made once per page and you should only call display() once so you'd include all the ads for display in that call.
Any help is appreciated.

**How do you configure Single Request Architecture for Google Publisher Tags in a react application?**

Thanks :)

**Update**:
I've found the clue but the implementation details are not clear. 
This is from the google documentation regarding enableSingleRequest():

```
Create one SRA request with all ad slots to best serve guaranteed
roadblocks or competitive exclusions, instead of sending 
SRA requests with one ad slot at a time.
```

So, now I"m wondering how do you achieve this in react - when the adSlot component only knows about the id of the google publisher tag where it is currently being rendered? I need to figure out some way to pass all the ids with one request on page load...